# Displaying MYSQL info using PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im creating a webpage which displays the information from my MYSQL database using php code. However, when I test the page, rather then displaying the information, the code itself appears instead of the information. i cant figure out why such is happening as i have used the code before with no problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game Portal</title>
        <style>
        //CSS CODE  
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="center">
                <?php
                    $table_name = "";
                    $host_name = "";
                    $user_name = "";
                    $password = "";
                    $db_name = "";
                    $db_link = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($db_link));
                    $query = "select Name, Cover from $table_name;"; 
                    $result = mysqli_query($db_link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_link));
                    echo "<table>";

                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
                                     echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td>";
                                     echo "<td align=right>{$row[1]}</td></tr>";
                                }

                        echo "</table>";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that i removed bits of the code that aren't needed for the php part in order to make it easier to read.

Comment: Is your file .html or .php? .html files won't be parsed by PHP unless you specifically set them to.

Comment: its html, how would i make it parse php?

Comment: Change extension to .php would be easiest way.

Comment: ok, but id like to keep the file as an html

Comment: @A22asin you don't want  to change the extension for SEO purpose or for  another reason?

Comment: @LeaTano my prof wants an html file with php code.

Comment: @A22asin that is weird. However, If you need to do this I am posting some answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Or

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

PHP File

[image]

Browser

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as your using .html files, if you really want to parse them as PHP (I wouldn't recommend it as if they don't contain PHP code, they will still be parsed adding overhead)

Add
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`
to your .htaccess (assuming your using Apache)

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite requests for (.*).html into a matching .php file. Pop the following into a .htaccess file in the directory where your wares are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

The page will then be visible as .html to your users, but obviously your PHP code gets processed. Presuming you have Apache as the server you use.